# 1D Interpolating subdivision for wavelet lifting schemes

Tags: interpolation, reference-request, dwt, discrete-wavelet-transform

I am looking into wavelet lifting methods first introduced by Swelden, and explained in this paper: [Build your own wavelets at home](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/naldi/lifting.pdf).

In this paper (in chapter 2 specifically), they discuss interpolating subdivision schemes defined in the presence of boundaries, however they do not provide any information regarding how to derive these schemes.

I am hoping to find a reference, (or even better a formula!) which might explain how to derive interpolating subdivision schemes of arbitrary degree, and in the presence of boundaries.

Comment: Did you check [Swelden's PhD thesis?](https://cm-bell-labs.github.io/who/wim/thesis/thesis.pdf)